# Hamcrest locators espresso

Tags: hamcrest

I have **id** for 2 elements(id:ib_done_card_name, id: et_card_name), but I can't locate them anyway. I have the error "matches multiple views in the hierarchy". I don't see anything else with the same **id**. 
I was trying to use that matcher, but it didn't work.

*onView(allOf(hasDescendant(allOf(withId(R.id.et_card_name), withParent(hasDescendant(withText("List")))))))*

[id:ib_done_card_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgKBR.png)

[et_card_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO73H.png)